# How can I hide an anchor element after clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to hide the `<a href= ...>` when the onclick in the button is clicked.
Can this be done in the javascript I already have, or do I need to make a new function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function actions($id, $action){

        $.ajax({
            url: "inc/actions.inc.php",
            data: {id : $id, action: $action},
            type: "POST",
        });
    }
</script>


<a href="#" id="125" class="list-group-item">
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
<button type="button" onclick="actions(125,'found')" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"> Found </button>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Inside of `actions` I think you could do `this.style.display = 'none'`

Comment: this.style.visibility = "hidden"; will do it too

Comment: I'm not sure having a button inside an anchor is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

It can absolutely be done in your existing code.

All you have to do is change the **[`style.display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)** of the target element to be `"none"` after calling your `$.ajax` method:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function actions($id, $action) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "inc/actions.inc.php",
      data: {
        id: $id,
        action: $action
      },
      type: "POST",
    });
    
    document.getElementById('125').style.display = "none";
  }
</script>


<a href="#" id="125" class="list-group-item">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <button type="button" onclick="actions(125,'found')" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"> Found </button>
  </div>
</a>
```

This can even be extended to utilise the ID passed through the function:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function actions($id, $action) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "inc/actions.inc.php",
      data: {
        id: $id,
        action: $action
      },
      type: "POST",
    });
    
    document.getElementById($id).style.display = "none";
  }
</script>


<a href="#" id="125" class="list-group-item">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <button type="button" onclick="actions(125,'found')" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"> Found </button>
  </div>
</a>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Call `hide()` on the `a` tag with the send id:

```
function actions($id, $action){

    $('#'+$id+').hide();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking for another approach which uses javascript event binding. This method allows you to use the `this` context, which can increase readability and also promote loose coupling of your event from the html.

```js
$("a.list-group-item button").click(actions)

function actions() {
  $(this).parents('a').hide();

  $.ajax({
    url: "inc/actions.inc.php",
    data: {
      id: this.id,
      action: this.value
    },
    type: "POST",
    error: ()=>{
     console.log("an error has occured"");
     $(this).parents('a').show();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="list-group-item">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <button id="125" type="button" onclick="actions()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="found">Found</button>
  </div>
</a>
```